Convert file paths in compilation buffer
The paths of files in my compilation buffer don't match the actual files on disk, because building my project happens in another context.
I want to convert the file paths in my compilation buffer, so that pressing enter on a compilation error opens the correct file.
Background
I build my project in a docker container. My local project folder is ~/src/mcu, and maps to the docker container's /src.
If my local file ~/src/mcu/app/myfile.c gives an error, it shows up in the compilation buffer as in /src/app/myfile.c.
When I try to open that file, I get prompted with:

Find this error in (default /src/app/myfile.c):

followed by another file suggestion that makes sense (the directory of the actual local file), but the file cannot be found.
My attempt
Seeing this answer, I decided to go for directory-abbrev-alist in my project root's .dir-locals.el (the manual):
;; .dir-locals.el
((nil . ((directory-abbrev-alist . (("^/src" . "~/src/mcu"))))))

The file seems to be read alright (tested by adding a syntax error, and getting en expected complaint). However, the links from the compilation buffer still don't work. What's more, if I M-h v directory-abbrev-alist while in a buffer at the project's root, I see that the variable is correct, but not if I do it from the compilation buffer.
I've also tried compilation-mode instead of nil. No luck.
I've tried an explicit absolute path instead of ~. No luck.
Finding the source file seems to work for files directly at the project root. Only files in a sub-directory give me that behavior.
Questions

is directory-abbrev-alist a reasonable solution for this use case? If not, what is? I'd like to keep this project specific, and not do this in my init file.
is the matter that the compilation buffer is not a file in my project root, therefore the .dir-locals.el does not apply on that buffer? How do I make it apply for a compilation buffer for that specific project?
how do I make the "pressing" enter on compilation error translate from one path to another?

